# How to remove duplicate records from table?

Tags: mysql

I have this table emp and i want to remove the duplicate record and here empno is not the primary key and original record must be there in table,only duplicate will remove

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per your posted table data you can use `distinct` while selecting from table

```
select distinct empno, ename, esal
from employee;
```